# Helper methods like Any() , Contains() when used inside FUNC predicate in where clause are not getting translated to Sql Server and hence erred out

Tags: ef-core-3.1

I am using .net core 3 with ef. When I use the below code, result is loaded

```
DbSet<User>().Where(User =>User.UserRoleMapping.Any(UserRoleMapping => UserRoleMapping.RoleID == (int)1))
```

But when I use predicate inside the where clause of dbset rather than an expression, here’s the error encountered

---

*The LINQ expression 'DbSet().Where(u => User.UserRoleMapping.Any(UserRoleMapping => UserRoleMapping.RoleID == 1))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038%C2%A0for) more information.*

---

Looks like the Any(), Contains() and all the helper methods are not getting translated to server execution due to limitation in Core 3.0 onwards, client side translation is restricted to top level projection only.

Is there any way I can progress with predicate without running into any problem.

Any insights?

Comment: Can you rewrite the query that you start from the `UserRoleMapping` entity and use `Include()` on the `User` entity instead?

Comment: @Progman - Have already tried including the UserRoleMapping, no luck

Comment: Not include the `UserRoleMapping`, but instead start from `DbSet<UserRoleMapping>()` instead.